# How does Adobe Fireworks store vector information, pages, and layers in PNG format?

Tags: png, vector-graphics, fireworks

How is fireworks able to store this extra information in a format that is otherwise flat raster. And is there any open source way to write similar vector, layered, paginated files in Png format that would be readable by fireworks?

Answer (score 1):

The PNG format allows for [ancillary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Ancillary_chunks) data chunks to store metadata aside from the image itself. I don't believe anyone's actually worked out the format that Adobe stores that data in though.

Comment: +1 You can use [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) (win app) to peek inside the chunks.